# How does svg use change the variable scope of xslt variables?

Tags: xml, svg, xslt

I am trying to access variables in a XSLT file combined with svg. The parameters are symbol and number corresponding to playing card values, which I want to draw. After drawing a card with xslt:for-each once the parameters are right and the playing card was drawn properly, but after using it twice, svg's use uses the same variable values as in the first iteration of xslt:for-each, thus generating the same grafic multiple times without changing the variable values, but outside of svg's use the variable values are different than inside.

```
<!-- right variable values outside the definition !-->
<text font-size="50">
<xsl:value-of select="$symbol"/>
</text>
<text font-size="50">
<xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
</text>
<use href="#draw_card""/>
<defs>
      <symbol id="draw_card">
           <!-- wrong variable values inside !-->
           <text font-size="50"><xsl:value-of select="$symbol"/></text>
           <text font-size="50"><xsl:value-of select="$number"/></text>
      </symbol>
</defs>
```

How can I change my code, such that the xslt variables remain unchanged inside the definition and I can draw my playing card with those new values?

Comment: It would help if you showed us minimal but complete samples to reproduce the problem. If there is a `for-each` around the snippet you have shown then it seems you would declare a symbol with the same id `draw_card` several times while `id` values are supposed to be unique. So perhaps you want something like `<use href="#draw_card_{position()}"/>` and `<symbol id="draw_card_[position()}">...`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Martin Honnen!

The id was indeed the issue here. I adjusted the code here by declaring the id as "draw_card_{position()}".

```
<!-- right variable values outside the definition !-->
<text font-size="50">
<xsl:value-of select="$symbol"/>
</text>
<text font-size="50">
<xsl:value-of select="$number"/>
</text>
<use href="#draw_card_{$position}"/>
<defs>
      <symbol id="draw_card_{$position}">
           <!-- right variable values inside !-->
           <text font-size="50"><xsl:value-of select="$symbol"/></text>
           <text font-size="50"><xsl:value-of select="$number"/></text>
      </symbol>
</defs>
```

-> The variables are "stored" in the id and can be accessed again inside of the definition!